# Definse CSS Rules for first element of input type

Tags: html, css

I want to adjust margins for my radio buttons, they shall be all the same except the first radio button which shouldn't have a margin-left of 15px (it should be 0). I tried to solve this with the :first-of-type keyword but then it will define rules for all input-types. How can I solve this by keeping CSS und HTML strictly divided and in a beatiful way ?

HTML:

```
<div class="payment-methods">
    <div class="method"><input name="1" type="radio"><label class="radio"><img src="https://lol-accs.com/images/ico_visa.jpg" alt=""></label></div>
    <div class="method"><input name="1" type="radio"><label class="radio"><img src="https://lol-accs.com/images/ico_visa.jpg" alt=""></label></div>
    <div class="method"><input checked="" name="1" type="radio"><label class="radio"><img src="https://lol-accs.com/images/ico_visa.jpg" alt=""></label></div>
    <div class="method"><input name="1" type="radio"><label class="radio"><img src="https://lol-accs.com/images/ico_visa.jpg" alt=""></label></div>
    <div class="method"><input name="1" type="radio"><label class="radio"><img src="https://lol-accs.com/images/ico_visa.jpg" alt=""></label></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.method, img, input {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.payment-methods input[type=radio]:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.payment-methods input[type=radio] {
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 15px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0apLmge9/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be targeting the first `<div class="method">` in this case, since the first-of-type is within it's containing element so your `input:first-of-type` will affect all of the radio buttons.

```
.payment-methods .method:first-of-type input[type=radio] {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0apLmge9/6/

Answer (score 0):

Target the first payment method.

```
.payment-methods .method:first-child input[type=radio] {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```